# How to flash root.zip in fastboot

Tags: rooting, fastboot

I need to flash the root zip I downloaded from Chainfire without having to install recovery like Clockworkmod. I have fastboot and adb and that's what I used to flash 4.4.4. This is for my Nexus 7 2013 Wifi. I have to leave in under 20 minutes, could someone write the correct fastboot command to do this

Comment: Answered with 5 minutes to spare!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1:** Unlock the bootloader; `fastboot oem unlock` This WILL wipe your device. Skip if already unlocked. Set up your device and put SuperSU.zip into it.
**Step 2:** Download the appropriate TWRP/CWM image for your device.
**Step 3:** Boot your phone into bootloader; `adb reboot bootloader`while the device is on or hold the power button and the volume down button while the device is off.
**Step 4:** Make sure your device is detected by fastboot; `fastboot devices`
**Step 5:** *Temporarily Boot* into recovery; `fastboot boot nameofrecovery.img`This will only boot the recovery, not install it.
**Step 6:** Flash the .zip file using the recovery and reboot.

You will have stock recovery and root access.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
adb sideload root.zip
```

That is generally the way for SuperSU. To be honest, a recovery would be better long term and in the time it takes for me to reply and you to read this you'd have it done! Might be worth considering. As far as I understand you need a custom recovery to do this. I would recommend installing one.

However, you could try this command:

```
fastboot -c "lge.kcal=0|0|0|x" boot customrecovery.img
```

This should allow you to **use** a recovery without installing. I don't recommend this as it is easier with a custom recovery and you can restore the stock one if and when you need it.

Alternatively you could try the [Nexus Root Tookit](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/) and untick "Custom Recovery". I have not tested it though.

Comment: The `fastboot flash recovery` **flashes** the recovery, not boots it without installing. That would be the second command. Also, it is worth noting that you **can not** root the device using `fastboot`, you need something that can mount the `/system` partition as writable; most preferably a recovery, but also a live system can be used.

Comment: Yeah I was rushing given the time limit, assumed he was rooted. Deleting this, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Best Method on Nexus

## Use: TWRP

http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/103

get ADB drivers + binary
(From cmd or Powershell)

> http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

## Linux "Drivers" + adb, fastboot (ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools*
```

## Windows commands - Open Powershell (as administrator)

1. command

   ```
   adb reboot bootloader
   ```

   ADB tells android to reboot to bootloader. Wait for reboot
2. command

   ```
   fastboot flash recovery TWRP-recovery.zip
   ```

if it doesnt like it, just unzip it.

In linux, instead of powershell = Terminal
First command "sudo su"

thats it...
PS: Almost forgot
TWRP will install and fix SU automatically.